# Relational vs XML vs Graph databases - pros and cons - convenience - future

Tags: sql, xml, database, graph, relational

I would like to discuss and get a good annalysis from experienced users about the topics. I work with all three of them.

- SQL -> Maturity. Constraints, triggers, distributed tables...
- XML -> Fast and powerful querying
- Graph -> Intuitively OOP, fastest and optimal in terms of transversions, joins, indexs etc. Easy prone for viewing through graphical interface by design.

So my question is, if time is the only thing not solvable, should graph databases be the future once they incorpore a powerful query engine like xquery plus all the features of established SQL databases (specially remote tables, constraints, triggers)?

What do you think its best for acquiring knowledge nowadays?

Comment: why this kind of questions get always censored?. There is a lot of people here which has a lot of knowledge and a very valid opinion. I think its a total legacy question and more tehnical than philosophical and this is the best place to formulate it. I think its very interesting for the community too

Comment: *It is difficult to make predictions, especially about the future* ...

Comment: its not a prediction, its an opinion of people who eventualy knows more than me, what can lead to a consensus, what can lead to the determined future itself

Comment: It's a good, valid topic for discussion; however, this is not the place to conduct the discussion - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: oops you are right. I saw so many of those I did not think it was against the style of SO

Comment: I voted to close my own question :)

Comment: Is there anywhere I could follow up on this question?